# Unable to change background color in android xml file

Tags: android

Whenever am trying to change the background color by using

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/SomeColor">
```

Am getting the error:

```
Failed to parse file E:\ADT\sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res\color\SomeColor.xml
```

I have cleared the project and even restarted it several times but I have been unsuccessful in getting rid of the error.

Comment: You are passing a file name, while you should pass a color name. Do you have colors defined in Somecolor.xml ?

Comment: Where is that `Somecolor` stored?

Comment: wht is SomeColor?? try with `@android:color/white`
And if you want your color add that color in `color.xml` and use as `color/SomeColor`

Comment: `Somecolor` might be an _ROCKET COLOR_!

Comment: Please post your SomeColor.xml along with the full path of your resource file

Comment: Note that RelativeLayout should not use Orientation, since it's relative positions (just sayin)

Comment: color/white (or) color/holo_purple (or) color/AnyColor thats why I commented as SomeColor as sometimes no color is working.

Comment: I have checked that all colors are defined in E:\ADT\sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res\color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/SomeColor">
```

**EDIT**

And make sure that you set your color properly. You should set in **strings.xml**.

`<color name="SomeColor">#ffff0000</color>`

Or you can set

```
android:background="#dcdcdc" // give the appropriate color code here.
```

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: Should I set <color name="SomeColor">#ffff0000</color> inside layout or outside? I have tried but getting error

Answer (score 0):

now u fetch xml file itself dont do this dude just try to fetch color name itself in that xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

         <color name="graycolor">#DCDCDC</color> 
         <color name="graycolor_press">#8B8B8B</color> 
    </resources>
```

Then fetch like this

```
<item android:drawable="@color/graycolor"/>
```

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawable="@color/graycolor"
 >
<resources>

         <color name="graycolor">#DCDCDC</color> 
         <color name="graycolor_press">#8B8B8B</color> 
    </resources>

Comment: y u take relative layout

Comment: Anuraag just make one xml with name SomeColor.xml in your drawable folder and then in your mainxml where u want to set  relative backround just set like this @android:color/graycolor" thats it